# How I can solve my php problem with a ContextErrorException

Tags: php

I have a problem :

> ContextErrorException
>
> Warning: Missing argument 4 for CategoryCore::getProducts(), called in
> /home/shinseka/www/NewPre_Prod/modules/featuredcategory/featuredcategory.php
> on line 101 and defined in Category.php line 904

this is the line 101 on featuredcategory.php :

```
        if($category->getProducts((int)Context::getContext()->language->id, 1) != '') {
```

Line 102 to 110

```
            $cat['name'] = $category->name[(int)Context::getContext()->language->id];
            $cat['products'] = $this->prepareBlocksProducts($category->getProducts((int)Context::getContext()->language->id, 1, 10, 'date_add', 'DESC'));
            array_push($categories,$cat);
        }
    }
    return array(
        'categories' => $categories,
    );
}
```

and Category.php line 904

**public function getProducts(**

line 904 to 916

```
public function getProducts(
    $idLang,
    $p,
    $orderyBy = null,
    $n,
    $orderWay = null,
    $getTotal = false,
    $active = true,
    $random = false,
    $randomNumberProducts = 1,
    $checkAccess = true,
    Context $context = null
) {
```

Comment: You don't have a default value for parameter `$n` when you defined `getProducts` function, so when you call `getProducts`, you must provide a value.

Comment: okay thanks a lot, so What I have to do or change on my code ?

Comment: You should add default value to parameter `$n`. We don't know what that parameter stands for, i.e. `$n = null,` or `$n = 0` etc.

Comment: okay then I change something and now I have a big error from MySQL